# How can I edit Excel Workbooks using XLRD or openpyxl while preserving charts?

Tags: python, xlrd, xlwt, openpyxl, xlutils

I have a workbook that has some sheets in it.  One of the sheets has charts in it.  I need to use xlrd or openpyxl to edit another sheet, but, whenever I save the workbook, the charts are gone.

Any workaround to this?  Is there another python package that preserves charts and formatting?

Comment: I'm still trying to find a solution to the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not possible with either but I hope to have it in openpyxl 2.x. Patches / pull requests always welcome! ;-)